# How to do for each and create array in XSLT - "flattened" data

Tags: for-loop, xslt, foreach, integration, xslt-2.0

I am using Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC) and trying to looping through the REST API array (that I cannot change), and check if for each element text_id value is exists( value > 0  ) and create for each element the count of the text id's.

Example of API:

```
<root>
   <element>
      <amount>1000</amount>
      <created_at>2021-01-05 12:38:05</created_at>
      <code />
      <name>John</name>
      **<request_id>5495</request_id>**
      <text_id_0>350</text_id_0>
      <text_id_19>0</text_id_19>
      <text_id_2>0</text_id_2>
      <text_id_3>0</text_id_3>
      <text_id_33>650</text_id_33>
      <text_id_4>0</text_id_4>
      <text_id_40>0</text_id_40>
      <text_id_5>0</text_id_5>
      <text_id_56>0</text_id_56>
      <text_id_6>0</text_id_6>
      <text_id_63>0</text_id_63>
      <url>2c8R2ScvhT36S2cFss3</url>
   </element>
   
   <element>
      <amount>3000</amount>
      <created_at>2021-01-02 12:38:05</created_at>
      <code />
      <name>Snow</name>
      **<request_id>5492344</request_id>**
      <text_id_0>0</text_id_0>
      <text_id_19>0</text_id_19>
      <text_id_2>13</text_id_2>
      <text_id_3>0</text_id_3>
      <text_id_33>0</text_id_33>
      <text_id_4>0</text_id_4>
      <text_id_40>0</text_id_40>
      <text_id_5>0</text_id_5>
      <text_id_56>0</text_id_56>
      <text_id_6>0</text_id_6>
      <text_id_63>0</text_id_63>
      <url>2c8Rd42S,dpWq24Cxxa*32</url>
   </element>
</root>
```

The unique column in each element is the **request_id** column.
We can see that for the element with request_id of 5495, there is 2 values in each **text_id_?**.

- ```
    <text_id_0>350</text_id_0>
  ```
- ```
   <text_id_33>650</text_id_33>
  ```

Check is needed here for each text_id_?, that I cannot change.
The columns name will not change.

I want to create for each that create XML output of :

```
<root>
  <element>
      <amount>1000</amount>
      <created_at>2021-01-05 12:38:05</created_at>
      **<code>1<code/>**
      <name>John</name>
      <request_id>5495</request_id>
      **<price>350</price>**
   </element>
    <element>
      <amount>1000</amount>
      <created_at>2021-01-05 12:38:05</created_at>
      **<code>2<code />**
      <name>John</name>
      <request_id>5495</request_id>
      **<price>650</price>**
   </element>
   <element>
      <amount>3000</amount>
      <created_at>2021-01-02 12:38:05</created_at>
      **<code>1<code />**
      <name>Snow</name>
      <request_id>5492344</request_id>
      **<price>13</price>**
   </element>
</root>
```

I'm understand that  the data is  "flattened".

So each **text_id_?** that has value more than 0, is a **new** element, and new sequnce number for **code** column in the xml output.

How could I should do with XPATH?

I'm using XSLT version 2.0

Comment: Is the shown wanted output complete for the input sample you have shown? Or all all the result for `name` `Snow` missing?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Its for all the result, ill update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an approach like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="element/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'text_id_')][. > 0]" mode="clone">
        <xsl:with-param name="id" select="."/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="clone">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="..">
      <xsl:with-param name="id" select="." tunnel="yes"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="element/url"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="element/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'text_id_')]">
    <xsl:param name="id" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test=". = $id">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

for an XSLT 2 processor replace `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` with the identity transformation template:

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think I cannot edit and use apply-templates when using Oracle Integration Cloud (OIC).
Any idea?

Comment: @LiorA, well, don't tag your questions as xslt ones if you can't use XSLT.